# difference between instantiation an interface or implementing an interface

Tags: java, interface

what is the difference between creating an Object of interface and implementing an interface

example :

```
 public interface A{
    public void testMethod(); 

 }
```

on way is creating an object of interface

```
 public class B{
    A a = new A(){
    @override
    public void testMethod(){  //implemtation here }
     };
  }
```

other way is

```
   public class B implements A
       {
       @override
       public void testMethod(){}
       }
```

Comment: Actually you can't instantiate an interface. You are creating an anonymous class that implements it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong:

here you anonymously implement interface and you alrady have instance of annonymouse class

```
 public class B{
    A a = new A(){
    @override
    public void testMethod(){  //implemtation here }
     };
  }
```

Here you create named implementation, you only create class without instantiate it.

```
 public class B implements A
       {
       @override
       public void testMethod(){}
       }
```

Comment: Also, your anonymous class (A) will have a reference to the B it was created in, which can lead to unforseen side-effects

Answer (score 0):

You can't create an object of interface. Interface it's an abstract class but with all the methods are abstract. In the first code you are creating an anonymous class (i recommend you to read about this feature in java) that implements the interface A, in this case you are limited with the interface's methods even if you define additional method in your implementation you can't call it. In the second code you are creating a class that implements the interface A which means that you have a class that at least contain all the methods defined in the interface A and you can add inside your class B other methods and call its.